# How to set up CSOM in Visual Studio?

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model, csom

Our Sharepoint site is on our company servers. I need to create a web app that can retrieve and post data from and to that site.

I use VS 2017, I tried to install Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client using Nuget, but that comes up with a "package restore failed" error. Should I be doing this with Nuget?

Could use some help and pointers as to how to set up the Client Side Object Model so I can start developing a web app that can make those data operations.

I believe the site is built with Sharepoint server 2013. And we use windows auth to manage site permissions.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make sure the SharePoint module is installed in VS 2017. Also try downloading the CSOM dlls from server and add reference them in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Previously you would have needed to install the SharePoint Client Side SDK to access the required assemblies. Fortunately Microsoft has [released Nuget packages for CSOM!](https://dev.office.com/blogs/sharepoint-csom-versions-for-on-premises-released-as-nuget-packages)

For on-prem SP2013 the package is:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2013.CSOM/

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, @Yousuf Jamil

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the visual studio 2017 in SharePoint server?

If so, you could add the reference from hive 15.

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

SharePoint Client Object Modal (CSOM).

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-client-object-modal-csom/

Comment: I am using Visual Studio in my own machine for dev. purposes. 
Does that change anything?